# EF Core many to many key duplicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am getting an issue about duplicate keys when merging many to many items.

I set up the entity key as

```
e => new { e.OwnerId, e.OwnedId }
```

To create new items, I use this code:

```
var newItem = dbContext.Add(new Item()).Entity;
newItem.Owner = owner;
newItem.Owned = dbContext.OtherItems.Find(item.Id);
```

Do I get the duplicate keys because of the way I set up the entity, the key for each new item would be `{ OwnerId = 0, OwnedId = 0 }` since I did not set the Ids explicitly (I just set the navigation properties)?

Or is it the way I am creating the new item that is incorrect?

Otherwise how would I check what the duplicate keys are as the exception message does not indicate which keys are duplicated and for which entity type?

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object[]

Comment: Try setting all the properties and then adding it to the context. So do everything and then call `dbContext.Add(...)`.

Comment: I tried that, also I tried removing all items that way add is not called(only remove will) but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Since you're using a composite key, no `Owner` may own the same `OtherItems` more than once. Is this the desired behavior? You shouldn't be running into any cases of `{ OwnerId = 0, OwnedId = 0 }`, however, to help find your issue you may be able to catch a `DbUpdateException` and check the `Entries` property for the rows that are causing the error.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12090) on the ef core git hub. What I ended up doing is remove all existing many to many items first from the database directly, then added them back through ef dbcontext. If I am able to reproduce it again I will for sure check the expcetion details more carefully.